# How do I allow Amazon s3 into my password protected directory?

Tags: .htaccess, amazon-s3

We're somewhat new to Amazon's s3 service and we've got a dev environment that is keeping out the public using an htaccess password. What do we need to add to our file to allow access to Amazon s3 so that it can fetch files from our site?

Edit: htaccess wasn't causing the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you clarify what you mean?

S3 is a file storage system only - that's it. You put files in there and pull them out with a URL. S3 cannot fetch files from your site (although I am not sure what you mean by that).

Do you want to provide access to your S3 files via your site? You can access them using a simple url:

For publicly visible files they are in the format:

```
http://s3.amazonaws.com/[bucket]/[key]
```

However, you can make your content [private](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/index.html?UsingAuthAccess.html) so it is not reachable by the standard url and only via a [signed, expiring url](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/index.html?S3_QSAuth.html).

Comment: I thought this was creating an error but it wasn't. Thanks though!